# Sitecore config: reference variable config files

Tags: .net, sitecore, config

Is it possible to dynamically include config files into Sitecore.config based on environmental variables?

I thought of something like this

```
<sc.include file="/App_Config/custom.$(HOSTNAME).config" />
```

which then should be translated to

```
<sc.include file="/App_Config/custom.manticore.config" />
```

Given that the hostname is "manticore".

Comment: You could just [SlowCheetah](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx) to transform the value using different build profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

There is a Sitecore Configuration Roles project on github ( https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Configuration-Roles ) which might be helpful though.

Remember that you need **Sitecore CMS 8.1 rev. 160302 (Update-2)** to use it.

Answer (score 1):

As @jammykam mentions, SlowCheetah transforms can allow you to create environment-specific config files based on build configurations.

You can also use release management software that supports token replacement to manage environment variables. During release it will replace the tokens with the environment-specific value you want.

A few examples:

- [Microsoft Release Management](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/release-management-vs.aspx)
- [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/)

Comment: Slow cheetah has worked for brilliantly for us.  We simply specify the variables with in octopus for each of our release configurations.